# another word for "most developed"

Tags: vocabulary

I'd like to say: "The development of H2 infrastructure is most ... in Germany."

- mature
- advanced
- common
- prominent
- widespread
- ...

Which is the best adjective and which of the list cannot be used in this structure?

The meaning is the following:

"Germany is the prospective lead market of H2 infrastructure due to continuous support by industrial stakeholders and the government."

Comment: Also take a look whether "*sophisticated*" would suffice.

Comment: Prevalent or Predominant perhaps?

Comment: Why not "H2 infrastructure is most developed|mature in Germany."

Comment: Seeing *common* and *widespread* on the list, I think "H₂ infrastructure is most established in Germany" is probably even better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'Developed' has several slightly different meanings. Which synonym you choose depends on which aspect you want to emphasize:

It can mean 'having had time to approach some ideal level of growth', in which case **mature** is the closest synonym.

It can also mean 'having the best technology', in which case **advanced** or **sophisticated** are close.

Finally, it can mean 'having had time to spread to many places'. For this sense, **widespread** would be appropriate. **Common** is similar.

I don't think **prominent** conveys the meaning you want, because it's about the level of recognition something gets, rather than about the thing itself.

Comment: Probably I will say "H2 infrastructure is most advanced in Germany."

Answer (score 1):

You are right to not want to use "developed" as saying two forms of "develop" in a row like that is jarring.

I'm assuming that there are various levels of development of H2 infrastructure and you are trying to say Germany has the most advanced level of development.

mature - This would apply if "H2 infrastructure" is a single thing that grows as it ages, but for an infrastructure to grow can mean a couple of different things, so it's too vague unless context explains what is meant by H2 infrastructure.  Mature also implies that it's "done" advancing or that the rate of advancing is slowing down - not sure if you want to mean this or not.

advanced - I would go with this one.  But "most advanced" when used directly in your sentence can mean just "very advanced."  So I would say "Germany's H2 infrastructure development is the most advanced."

common - Your sentence would mean that the *event* "development of H2 infrastructure" happens the most in Germany, not anything about the level of development of its H2 infrastrcture.

prominent - This means that "development of H2 infrastrcture" is *most visible* compared to other countries (maybe from a helicopter?), but not saying anything about the level of development of that H2 infrastructure.

widespread - THis means that "development of H2 infrastructure" covers most of the area of the country or area you are talking about, but does not say anything about the level of development of that H2 infrastructure.

Answer (score 0):

'Cutting-edge' could be used here.

Lets see the MacMillan's definition of it

Cutting edge is - 'the most modern and advanced point in the development of something' -

For example

1. These models are at the cutting edge of computer design.
2. The most cutting edge designs of cars could be found in Germany.
3. In the era of the Interent you should keep up with the cutting edge advertising to stay in a competition.

However, to put this in your sentence it will have to modified a bit as

1. Germany's got the most cutting-edge development of H2 infrastructure in the world.